# How to obtain the average amplitude of a signal from a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, averages

If I have the following differential equation

```
v'[t] == Subscript[μ, 0]/
  2 (v[t] Sin[τ + ω ϵ τ] + 
    v[t] Sin[
      Subscript[τ, 
       2] + ω ϵ Subscript[τ, 2]] + 
    Subscript[μ, 0] α v[t] -  
    γ v[t]^3 - η v[t])
```

How can I find the average value of *v*, where $\omega$=1, $\tau$=3, $\tau_2$=3, $\epsilon$=0.1, $\mu_0$=5, α=0.5, $\gamma$=0.5, and $\eta$=0.02?

```
ω=1; τ=3; Subscript[τ,2]=3; ϵ=0.1; Subscript[μ,0]=5; α=0.5; γ=0.5; η=0.02;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ω = 1; τ[0] = 3; τ[2] = 3; ϵ = 1/10; μ[0] = 5;
α = 1/2; γ = 1/2; η = 1/50;

eqn = v'[t] == μ[0]/2 (v[t] Sin[τ[0] + ω ϵ τ[0]] + 
      v[t] Sin[τ[2] + ω ϵ τ[2]] + μ[0] α v[t] - γ v[t]^3 - η v[t]) // Simplify;

sol = DSolve[eqn, v, t]

(* {{v -> Function[{t}, -((2 E^(1/5 (t - 20 C[1]) (31 + 25 Sin[33/10])) Sqrt[
         31 + 25 Sin[33/10]])/(Sqrt[
        1 + 25 E^(2/5 (t - 20 C[1]) (31 + 25 Sin[33/10]))]))]}, {v -> 
   Function[{t}, (2 E^(1/5 (t - 20 C[1]) (31 + 25 Sin[33/10])) Sqrt[
       31 + 25 Sin[33/10]])/(Sqrt[
      1 + 25 E^(2/5 (t - 20 C[1]) (31 + 25 Sin[33/10]))])]}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

The second solution is the negative of the first

```
(v[t] /. sol[[1]]) == -(v[t] /. sol[[2]]) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

In the limit, the solutions are

```
lim = Assuming[Element[C[1], Reals],
  Limit[v[t] /. sol, t -> Infinity]]

(* {-(2/5) Sqrt[31 + 25 Sin[33/10]], 2/5 Sqrt[31 + 25 Sin[33/10]]} *)
```

If the initial condition is set to the limit, the function is constant for all `t`

```
sol2 = DSolve[eqn && v[0] == lim[[2]], v, t]

(* {{v -> Function[{t}, 2/5 Sqrt[31 + 25 Sin[33/10]]]}} *)
```

Verifying that the constant satisfies the equation,

```
eqn /. sol2 // Simplify

(* {True} *)
```

The average value is just this constant (and its negative for the other solution).

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253201/linearization-of-the-ode-system-problems

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the initial value v[0].

If v[0]==0 then the soluntion is 0 for alll t.

Otherwise it gives this :

```
Manipulate[Plot[
  NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][v][t] == 
      5/2 (2.1645086117135035` v[t] - 0.5` v[t]^3), v[0] == initVal}, 
    v, {t, 0, 10}][tt], {tt, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3, 3}}]
 , {{initVal, 1}, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

I let you proove the very probable monotonicity and saturation.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253201/linearization-of-the-ode-system-problems